Flutter web app: certificate in HTTPS post call
My problem is with a Flutter app that does POST requests and it needs to do that with a certificate.  I've seen many solutions, but none seem to work for me.
I have a web app - written in Dart/Flutter - which communicates with a back-end server - written in Golang.  This Go program can work as http and https like this:
http.HandleFunc("/", processRequest)
if CM.HttpType == "http" {
    fmt.Println("HTTP Server started")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(CM.HttpPort, nil))
} else {
    fmt.Println("HTTPS Server started")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(CM.HttpPort, CM.CertFile, CM.CertKey, nil))
}

(The variables starting CM. all come from a properties file)
In the first stages of development I used HTTP and that works fine, but obviously I need to change it to HTTPS.
For the rest of the development I have used MkCert to install a certificate and use that in my Go server.  In prod it will be Let's Encrypt.
Connecting to said server works fine if I try it out with Curl, or even with a browser where the certificate is installed too (sort of ... it does not return data as in the browser it's a GET, but at least the TLS handshake succeeds).
But ultimate goal is for the Flutter web app to connect to the server with the certificate.  Running without it inevitably gives TLS handshake errors.
Solutions I've seen all revolve around the creation of a custom SecurityContext and then load the certificate in there from the assets folder (This copied from a proposed solution I found elsewhere on StackOverflow ...):
Future<HttpClient> createHttpClientWithPinnedCertificate() async {
    final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    final String certificate = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/localhost.pem");
    securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificate.codeUnits);
    return HttpClient(context: securityContext);
}

And then do the call basically like this (it is a simplified version of what I use in the app):
final HttpClient httpClient = await createHttpClientWithPinnedCertificate();
final http.IOClient ioClient = http.IOClient(httpClient);

const url = "192.168.144.1:8945";
try {
    var response = await ioClient.post(
        Uri.https(url, "", {"req": "1"}),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
        body: '{"id":"12"}'
    );
    fmt.Println(response.body);
}    
catch (e) {
    fmt.Println(e.toString();
}

But in the Flutter app I cannot get it running.  Well ... I can if I run it as a Windows app (unfortunately I need to use Windows).  Then it works like a charm.
But if I run it as a web app it fails because apparently that does not support a custom SecurityContext.  Error:
DartError: Unsupported operation: default SecurityContext getter

(It does not help using final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext(); instead)
So ... the question remains ... how do I pass a certificate to a POST request within the web app.  Is that at all possible?
